# Recursive Algorithm to check if a win is possible in Nim game

Tags: c#, recursion

I found the following code to to check if a win is possible the game Nim. The comments suggest it is written by someone who understands what they are doing, yet the output seems wrong, unless I've completely misunderstood the purpose of the code. I want to use recursion to determine if a win if possible for the next player to play, given a particular number of remaining stones (value for `n`). Can anyone explain why the code doesn't work correctly please? I.e it returns `true` for all but 2 cases.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int numStix = 1; numStix <= 20; numStix++)
        {
            bool willWin = nimCalc(numStix);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of sticks: " + numStix + " Will win: " + willWin);
        }
    }

    public static bool nimCalc(int n)
    {
        bool x = false;
        //Base cases that guarantees player 1 will lose
        if (n == 1 || n == 4)
        {
            x = false;
        }
        //Base cases that guarantees player 1 will win
        else if (n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 6)
        {
            x = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //If n>6, it calls this recursively to subtract number of sticks to get to winning position
            x = nimCalc(n - 2);
            //If above method does not guarantee a win, it uses this recursively to obtain win
            if (x == false)
            {
                x = nimCalc(n - 1);
            }
        }

        //Returns boolean
        return x;
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/25MeDc

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking of a different "Nim" game, but knowing just the number of remaining sticks is insufficient to describe the state of a game, as the way they are separated into heaps/piles/levels is also relevant. A game is winnable if XOR-ing the number of sticks in each level results in a non-zero value (in which case the correct move is one that forces the XOR to be zero, though this may change in the "end-game" depending on whether the winner is the one that takes the last stick, or forces their opponent to).

Comment: I think it's for a much simplified version with n stones and you can take 1,2, or 3 at a time.